# Unable to copy/paste text in cmd.exe without splits

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, copy-paste

I need to copy/cut and paste the following verbatim in cmd.exe:

```
                     <<<< Identifier Token Start >>>>
853A7223817D29062140F28C8C4E1439
D57FC143B6897AD1A51CC32EB660423F
6CDAF406A0FA0A6610851C52511A8477
A9DEE6B5CD21918F3F6F2ADDC6411038
C58F673EF3DF253142650A88FEA930A5
E4CC3397F5D1082D78A977B50FB007FC
60D3206E83516B00523661E5EB27EA72
44FECBC38D310EF4F0AA462A072DA649
3A5BFCA82F92671B3992496F7F49A269
E8AD1A14E23A39CD68313C4DD421C816
33BF1E277F32E29DD31F4FE0961153C8
47BE975E3A43793C6A17B589F95347EA
9315E80E8E36B5C853C77C4B6C425893
EF1F7A1A0A6E05A3F4D296C0963F5E34
98A383EFD75588D5CE2B351E409B99B9
41BC42FE4746108CAF9F486E5E5B1DD7
<<<<< Identifier Token End >>>>>
--------------------------------
```

Every time I try, it splits it every two rows. How can I get this to work?

Comment: A workaround is put that in VIM  and use  SHIFT+j (J).

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? With some context you will get better answers.

Comment: @ChrisF the answers seem spot on.  no need for more context. Hennes's answer might have not worked 'cos perhaps the text is too long even for the widest cmd window, but other answers should work for her for sure even if hennes's doesn't. (assuming she asked her question right and it looks like it's probably right)

Comment: ok if u go to htcdev.com u can see exactly what im trying to do go to unlock bootloader and keep goin till u get to step 9 and 10 and u can see but i have tried it all and still cant get it but i know it can be done

Comment: nevermind thanks for yalls suggestions and help i got it figured out now

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect output to clipboard, which will keep the formating

e.g.

```
Type C:\temp\test.txt |CLIP
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it really need to be in cmd.exe? If so try to make the cmd.exe window wider.

Right click it to get this menu:
[image]

Then select either properties or defaults (known bug in win7, both due the same thing. In XP those are different. Properties being for one session, defaults for all sessions).

[image]

However, why do you need to paste it in cmd.exe?

It seems much more likely that you want to put it in a text file. (E.g. use notepad to create token.txt and paste it there). However without more background this is guess work.

Comment: I have to do it from CMD because I'm trying to unlock my bootloader on my HTC phone and HTC dev has to receive it like this for some reason so I can  get the unlock code to install a custom OS Android 4.1.